# Dates and time zone codes around a DST change

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm testing how dates are calculated and displayed (with time zone codes) around a daylight savings change.

In the UK, at 1am on the 30th March 2014, we enter DST, and go from GMT to BST. The time jumps from `2014-03-30 00:59:59 GMT` to `2014-03-30 02:00:00 BST`.

I've hit a strange issue replicating this with the following code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def is_dst(d, tz):
    assert d.tzinfo is None  # we want a naive datetime to localize
    return tz.localize(d).dst() != timedelta(0)

start_datetime = datetime(2014, 03, 30, 0, 0, 0)
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

# Increment using timedelta
print 'This doesn\'t work:'
d = start_datetime
for i in range(5):
    print str(d) + ' ' + tz.tzname(d, is_dst=is_dst(d, tz))
    d += timedelta(minutes=30)  # Add 30 minutes

# Increment by adding seconds to epoch
print 'This works:'
epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
timestamp = (start_datetime - epoch).total_seconds()
for i in range(5):
    d = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    print str(d) + ' ' + tz.tzname(d, is_dst=is_dst(d, tz))
    timestamp += 30 * 60  # Add 30 minutes
```

The output is:

```
This doesn't work:
2014-03-30 00:00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00 GMT
2014-03-30 01:00:00 GMT <- invalid time
2014-03-30 01:30:00 GMT <- invalid time
2014-03-30 02:00:00 BST
This works:
2014-03-30 00:00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00 GMT
2014-03-30 02:00:00 BST
2014-03-30 02:30:00 BST
2014-03-30 03:00:00 BST
```

I have marked on the output where the invalid times are. Those times do not exist on the wallclock, there is no 1am or 1:30am on the 30th March 2014, so I'm not sure why it is being displayed.

The same process but done in a slightly different way yields the correct results. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, *both* sections of code are incorrect.  Running your exact code on my machine (in US Pacific Time zone), the bottom section returns:

```
2014-03-29 17:00:00 GMT
2014-03-29 17:30:00 GMT
2014-03-29 18:00:00 GMT
2014-03-29 18:30:00 GMT
2014-03-29 19:00:00 GMT
```

This is because `fromtimestamp` uses the computer's *local* time zone when none is specified.  If I just switch the `fromtimestamp` to `utcfromtimestamp`, it will use a naive value - The results then get put in the correct time zone, but it gives the same results as the first section - showing the two invalid times.

The problem is rectified by using the `normalize` method from the pytz `timezone` instance.  Unfortunately, you're keeping `d` as a *naive* datetime, so you can't normalize it without localizing it first, and when done you'll have to make it naive again.  This *works*, but makes for some messy code:

```
# Increment using timedelta
print 'This works:'
d = start_datetime
for i in range(5):
    print str(d) + ' ' + tz.tzname(d, is_dst=is_dst(d, tz))
    d += timedelta(minutes=30)  # Add 30 minutes
    d = tz.normalize(tz.localize(d)).replace(tzinfo=None)

# Increment by adding seconds to epoch
print 'This works too:'
epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
timestamp = (start_datetime - epoch).total_seconds()
for i in range(5):
    d = tz.normalize(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)).replace(tzinfo=None)
    print str(d) + ' ' + tz.tzname(d, is_dst=is_dst(d, tz))
    timestamp += 30 * 60  # Add 30 minutes
```

Output:

```
This works:
2014-03-30 00:00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00 GMT
2014-03-30 02:00:00 BST
2014-03-30 02:30:00 BST
2014-03-30 03:00:00 BST
This works too:
2014-03-30 00:00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00 GMT
2014-03-30 02:00:00 BST
2014-03-30 02:30:00 BST
2014-03-30 03:00:00 BST
```

Of course, the whole thing could be simplified by using *aware* datetimes early:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
start_datetime = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 03, 30, 0, 0, 0))

# Increment using timedelta
print 'This works:'
d = start_datetime
for i in range(5):
    print str(d) + ' ' + d.tzname()
    d = tz.normalize(d + timedelta(minutes=30))  # Add 30 minutes

# Increment by adding seconds to epoch
print 'This works too:'
epoch = datetime.fromtimestamp(0, pytz.utc)
timestamp = (start_datetime - epoch).total_seconds()
for i in range(5):
    d = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)
    print str(d) + ' ' + d.tzname()
    timestamp += 30 * 60  # Add 30 minutes
```

Output:

```
This works:
2014-03-30 00:00:00+00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00+00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 02:00:00+01:00 BST
2014-03-30 02:30:00+01:00 BST
2014-03-30 03:00:00+01:00 BST
This works too:
2014-03-30 00:00:00+00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 00:30:00+00:00 GMT
2014-03-30 02:00:00+01:00 BST
2014-03-30 02:30:00+01:00 BST
2014-03-30 03:00:00+01:00 BST
```

Note that you no longer need the `is_dst` function, as you can now get the `tzname` directly from the aware `datetime` instance.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the heads-up on normalize! Regarding using `tzname` on the aware `datetime`, it seems that just calls `self.tzinfo.tzname(self)` which leaves the `is_dst` argument of `tzname` to `None`. The [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api) say this will raise an error on ambiguous dates. Does the ambiguity only occur with naive `datetimes`?

Comment: Yeah, the docs aren't clear on that point.  That whole section is mostly about checking naive `datetime` values against the `timezone` instance.  If you call `tzname` on a `timezone` instance with an aware `datetime`, you'll get an error "Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)".  Aware values can't really be ambiguous, because they know their offset from UTC.  Consider also that you can pass `is_dst=True/False` to the `localize` method if you know you're passing in an ambiguous naive value.  If you don't pass that, it assumes `False`.

Comment: `tz.localize()` along may return non-existing time. If you are sure that the input naive datetime object refers to the time that exists in the `tz` timezone then use `is_dst=None` to assert that.

Comment: you could use `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz)`

Comment: Python stdlib relies on `time.time()` returing time in POSIX encoding. It means that `epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)`

Comment: Your first code fragment might fail in Autumn then the same local time may repeat (northern hemisphere). `tz.localize(d)` always chooses the same tzinfo for ambiguous times.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall: beware, the first ("messy") code example is incorrect. It fails if the start date is 2014-10-26

Answer (score 1):

Here's [@Matt Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26027487/4279) modified according to [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021782/dates-and-time-zone-codes-around-a-dst-change#comment40824752_26027487):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
#NOTE: is_dst=None asserts that the local time exists and unambiguous
start_datetime = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 03, 30, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=None)

# increment using timedelta
print 'This works:'
d = start_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc) # use UTC to do arithmetic
for _ in range(5):
    local = d.astimezone(tz) # use local timezone for display only
    print("\t{:%F %T %Z%z}".format(local))
    d += timedelta(minutes=30) # works in UTC

# increment by adding seconds to epoch
print 'This works too:'
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
timestamp = (start_datetime - epoch).total_seconds()
for i in range(5):
    local = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz)
    print("\t{:%F %T %Z%z}".format(local))
    timestamp += 30 * 60  # add 30 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks.  I always appreciate your attention to detail.  So if I understand correctly, you're advocating always doing math in UTC, right?  In general, I think that's a good practice, however I think `normalize` mitigates most of the issues.   I do appreciate that passing `is_dst=None` will cause a `NonExistentTimeError` if passed an invalid local time.  I'm surprised that that is required though.  I would expect the exception regardless of that setting.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @MattJohnson: the actual error in your code is desribed in [my last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021782/dates-and-time-zone-codes-around-a-dst-change/26059072?noredirect=1#comment40825021_26027487), everything else is just nitpicking.

Comment: @MattJohnson: `normalize` also works (it is essentially a variant of `astimezone()` that works with invalid dates). The preference is in failure mode: if I forget `astimezone()` in my code then the worst that can happen is that I see UTC dates instead of local dates (the datetime is aware;  there is explicit `+0000` in the output). If you forget `normalize()` then you may get wrong time.

Comment: Right, so working from the assumption that the input value is nonambiguous, then all is good.  But if the input is variable, then it would be important to check for ambiguous or invalid time, raising an error, or letting the user chose which instance of the ambiguous value they wanted.

Comment: @MattJohnson: try your code around DST transition in autumn. Compare the result with my code (I have not done it but I think your code should fail).

Comment: Just tried and if I start with `datetime(2014,10,26,0,0,0)` (and increase to `range(10)` for visibility) - everything works fine.  It's only if I input an ambiguous value like `datetime(2014,10,26,1,0,0)` that it assumes `is_dst=False`, which doesn't show the transition.  If I set `is_dst_True`, then it again shows ok.  So I think the general logic is sound - it's just the input that you have to be careful on.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I've tried your code with `datetime(2014,10,26,0,0,0)`. It fails as I've expected. I'm talking about your first (messy) code example.

Comment: Oh, Gotcha.  I thought you meant the second one.  In that case - I absolutely agree with your assesement.  Good call.